# Set local windows Registry with wamp apache server

Tags: php, wamp, regedit

I need to modify the windows proxy from my local WampServer application.

For that, I want to change registry keys, but it does not work. I think WampServer blocks me, but I do not find how to unlock it.

I tried this code :

````
exec("REG QUERY \"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" /v ProxyEnable", $proxyenable);```
````

This returns me the value `0`.
But when I want to change the variable, I do

````
exec("REG ADD \"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f", $proxyenable);```
````

The key does not change.

Comment: I already checked "Allow service to interact with desktop" of my wampapache service.

Comment: I tried to run the command line with the windows prompt "cmd" and it's works but not with wamp